# Searching for objects in a JSON that have a DateTime attribute that is within a certain number of days/months/years C#

Tags: c#, json, linq, datetime

I'm quite new to programming, just finishing up the final project for a bootcamp. My project is a console app that does some basic inventory management stuff. It stores purchase price, purchase place, purchase date, name, and expiration date if applicable. What I want to do is to be able to search all the objects in the JSON for objects with an expiration date either within a certain range of days/months/years or all objects with an expiration before x date.

I have searched and either I've not found applicable things or my level of understanding isn't high enough to be able to apply answers to my problem. Below is a sample of my JSON to show the various attributes.

```
    "productName": null,
    "productPurchasePrice": 0.0,
    "productPurchasePlace": null,
    "productPurchaseDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "productExpirationDate": null,
    "SKU": 0
  },
  {
    "productName": "shoe",
    "productPurchasePrice": 1.0,
    "productPurchasePlace": "Bob's Shoe Distributors",
    "productPurchaseDate": "1212-12-12T00:00:00",
    "productExpirationDate": null,
    "SKU": 1
  },
  {
    "productName": "Neutrogena Skin Clear Foundation",
    "productPurchasePrice": 5.12,
    "productPurchasePlace": "Walgreens",
    "productPurchaseDate": "1111-11-11T00:00:00",
    "productExpirationDate": "2023-12-14T00:00:00",
    "SKU": 1
  }
```

A lot of it is null but this is just for demonstration/testing purposes.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: You need to deserialize the JSON to a collection of products and use WHERE LINQ method to filter the list based on your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to do this would be to deserialise the JSON content into an array of objects that map on the JSON schema. With that in place you can then iterate over those objects and do whatever sort of comparisons you need to.

For example, using [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
//The name of each property in this class matches those in the JSON example
public class JSONObject
{
    public string productName { get; set; }
    public double productPurchasePrice { get; set; }
    public string productPurchasePlace { get; set; }
    public DateTime productPurchaseDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? productExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public int SKU { get; set; }
}

...
var json = "<snip>";
var deserialisedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JSONObject>>(json);

foreach(var deserialisedObject in deserialisedJson)
{
    if(deseriliasedObject.productExpirationDate == null)
        continue;

    //Do your checks on expiration dates here
}
```